# WPF - Display Image in Wrappannel along with textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, winforms, listview

Hi stackoverflow experts,
Recently only I have started coding in WPF and stuck somewhere.
I have to display the list of the image along with the text, I tried to find on google but as usual all are using hard coded values.

Step 1: In XAML file I have used the  along with the wrap panel and code is below :

```
 <ListView Width="auto" Name="listviewSource" BorderBrush="{x:Null}">
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
          <ItemsPanelTemplate>
              <WrapPanel Width="auto" Height="150" Orientation="Vertical" UseLayoutRounding="True" / >
           </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
       </ListView>
```

Step 2: Currently I am able to bind all image successfully, and code :

```
Image imageData = new Image();
List<Image> ImageList = new List<Image>();  // List of Image
List<string> imageName = new List<string>();  // list of name 

imageData = bitmapData // here bitmapData is having data which is already computed
imageName.Add(name); // This is the issue, how to display name below image 
ImageList.Add(imageData );
listviewSource.ItemSource = ImageList;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a `Label` or a `TextBlock` in the XAML where you want to put the names, and you should set the `imageName` to it.

Something like this in XAML:

```
        <ListView Width="auto" Name="listviewSource" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Margin="10,10,10,10">
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel Width="auto" Height="150" Orientation="Vertical" UseLayoutRounding="True" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <Image Name="DisplayedImage" Height="100" Width="100"/>
        <Label Name="ImageName" Content="ImagesName" Height="32" Width="93"/>
    </ListView>
```

CS file:

```
        Image imageData = new Image();
        List<Image> ImageList = new List<Image>();  // List of Images
        List<string> imageName = new List<string>();  // list of names
        string name= "...";

        BitmapImage myBitmapImage = new BitmapImage();

        //Setting BitmapImage properties must be done within a BeginInit and EndInit block.
        myBitmapImage.BeginInit(); 
        myBitmapImage.UriSource= new Uri(@"C:\Users\...\StackOverflow.bmp");
        myBitmapImage.DecodePixelWidth = 100;
        myBitmapImage.EndInit();

        imageData.Source= myBitmapImage; // here bitmapData is having data which is already computed
        imageName.Add(name);
        ImageName.Content= name;// This is the issue, how to display name below image
        
        DisplayedImage.Source = myBitmapImage;
        ImageList.Add(imageData);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `ListView` gets its `ItemSource` from ImageList. `imageName` is not used anywhere. What you want is to also bind this to your `ListView`. My suggestion would be to create a class `MyImageClass` that contains a `Property` of type Image and another `Property` for type `string` and connect your `listviewSource` to `list<MyImageClass>`. And in your user control, inside the `WrapPanel`, add `<Image/>` and `<Label/>` and bind them to the members `myImage` and `myImageName`.